# I created a stored procedure while executing no error but running it manually it showing error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I created one stored procedure; it executed successfully but while executing manually it is showing error.

Here's my stored proc

```
USE [chandru]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
alter procedure [dbo].[Insert_BandWidthDetails]          
@CurrentState nvarchar(50),@Process nvarchar(100),@DateTime nvarchar(100),@IPaddress nvarchar(50),@UploadedBytes nvarchar(max),@DownloadedBytes nvarchar(max),@Duration nvarchar(200),@FileSize nvarchar(max),@StreamId nvarchar(100),@PlayerId nvarchar(100),
@UserName nvarchar(200),@UserId nvarchar(200),@CountryName nvarchar(100),@RegionName nvarchar(100),@Latitude nvarchar(100),@Longitude nvarchar(100),@City nvarchar(100)           
as          
begin    


declare @Sql nvarchar(max)     

set @Sql='declare @countbandwidthtable int  select @countbandwidthtable=COUNT(*) from BandWidth'+@UserName+@UserId+
   +'if(@countbandwidthtable>0)
    begin
        declare @count int  select @count=COUNT(*) from BandWidth'+@UserName+@UserId+' where CurrentState='''+@CurrentState+''' and Process='''+@Process+''' and DateTime='''+@DateTime+''' and IPaddress='''+@IPaddress+''' and UploadedBytes='''+@UploadedBytes+''' and DownloadedBytes='''+@DownloadedBytes+''' and Duration='''+@Duration+''' and FileSize='''+@FileSize+''' and StreamId='''+@StreamId+''' and PlayerId='''+@PlayerId+''' and UserName='''+@UserName+''
        +'if(@count=0)          
        begin          
            insert into BandWidth'+@UserName+@UserId+' values('''+@CurrentState+''','''+@Process+''','''+@DateTime+''','''+@IPaddress+''','''+@UploadedBytes+''','''+@DownloadedBytes+''','''+@Duration+''','''+@FileSize+''','''+@StreamId+''','''+@PlayerId+''','''+@UserName+''','''+@CountryName+''','''+@RegionName+''','''+@Latitude+''','''+@Longitude+''','''+@City+''')       
        end         
    end
else
    begin
        select * into BandWidth'+ @UserName+ cast(@UserID as nvarchar(max)) +' from BandWidthSample where 1=2
       insert into BandWidth'+@UserName+@UserId+' values('''+@CurrentState+''','''+@Process+''','''+@DateTime+''','''+@IPaddress+''','''+@UploadedBytes+''','''+@DownloadedBytes+''','''+@Duration+''','''+@FileSize+''','''+@StreamId+''','''+@PlayerId+''','''+@UserName+''','''+@CountryName+''','''+@RegionName+''','''+@Latitude+''','''+@Longitude+''','''+@City+''')      
    end '     
 exec(@Sql)
end
```

After execution of this stored procedure, command is successfully and now I am inserting:

```
Insert_BandWidthDetails 'stream','play','11:17:00','10.0.3.0','12344','1234','2.09','22','1','11223','sample','31','india','asd','23','23','chennai'
```

I am getting the error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '>'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near 'stream'
>   Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
>   Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')             end '.

I don't know how to clear this error, I didn't find any error near '>' this symbol, can you guys help me out to clear this error?

Comment: Comment out the exec(@sql) statement and add a print @Sql statement. Your statement will print in the message window. Copy the statement and try to run that in a new query window. You should be able to see the syntax error easily, especially if you use intellisense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the design where you have a single table per user, your issue is that the first line of SQL doesn't have a space before the IF statement. If you want line breaks in the SQL, then you need to add `+ CHAR(10)` and not have the line breaks directly in the code.

If you are keeping the dynamic SQL, I would suggest reformatting it the set statement as follows:

```
set @Sql='declare @countbandwidthtable int' + CHAR(10) + 
         'select @countbandwidthtable=COUNT(*) from BandWidth' + @UserName + @UserId + CHAR(10) +
         'if(@countbandwidthtable>0)' + CHAR(10) +
           'begin' + CHAR(10) +
             'declare @count int' + CHAR(10) +
             'select @count=COUNT(*) from BandWidth'+@UserName+@UserId+' where CurrentState='''+@CurrentState+''' and Process='''+@Process+''' and DateTime='''+@DateTime+''' and IPaddress='''+@IPaddress+''' and UploadedBytes='''+@UploadedBytes+''' and DownloadedBytes='''+@DownloadedBytes+''' and Duration='''+@Duration+''' and FileSize='''+@FileSize+''' and StreamId='''+@StreamId+''' and PlayerId='''+@PlayerId+''' and UserName='''+@UserName+'' + CHAR(10) +
             'if(@count=0)' + CHAR(10) +
               'begin' + CHAR(10) +
                 'insert into BandWidth'+@UserName+@UserId+' values('''+@CurrentState+''','''+@Process+''','''+@DateTime+''','''+@IPaddress+''','''+@UploadedBytes+''','''+@DownloadedBytes+''','''+@Duration+''','''+@FileSize+''','''+@StreamId+''','''+@PlayerId+''','''+@UserName+''','''+@CountryName+''','''+@RegionName+''','''+@Latitude+''','''+@Longitude+''','''+@City+''')' + CHAR(10) +
               'end' + CHAR(10) +
           'end' + CHAR(10) +
         'else' + CHAR(10) +
           'begin' + CHAR(10) +
             'select * into BandWidth'+ @UserName+ cast(@UserID as nvarchar(max)) +' from BandWidthSample where 1=2' + CHAR(10) +
             'insert into BandWidth'+@UserName+@UserId+' values('''+@CurrentState+''','''+@Process+''','''+@DateTime+''','''+@IPaddress+''','''+@UploadedBytes+''','''+@DownloadedBytes+''','''+@Duration+''','''+@FileSize+''','''+@StreamId+''','''+@PlayerId+''','''+@UserName+''','''+@CountryName+''','''+@RegionName+''','''+@Latitude+''','''+@Longitude+''','''+@City+''')' + CHAR(10) +
            'end' + CHAR(10)
```

However, I would strongly encourage you, if possible, to just have a single BandWidth table that contains columns that hold the UserName and UserId. Then you won't have to have dynamic SQL at all.

Comment: That's good news. Since the answer solved the problem for you, can you check the checkbox next to the answer so that future visitors will know the answer fixed the problem for you?

Comment: ya sure ,i did it. Once again Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to make that change:

Here

```
declare @count int  select @count=COUNT(*) from BandWidth'+@UserName+@UserId+' where CurrentState='''+@CurrentState+''' and Process='''+@Process+''' and DateTime='''+@DateTime+''' and IPaddress='''+@IPaddress+''' and UploadedBytes='''+@UploadedBytes+''' and DownloadedBytes='''+@DownloadedBytes+''' and Duration='''+@Duration+''' and FileSize='''+@FileSize+''' and StreamId='''+@StreamId+''' and PlayerId='''+@PlayerId+''' and UserName='''+@UserName+''
```

to

```
declare @count int  select @count=COUNT(*) from BandWidth'+@UserName+@UserId+' where CurrentState='''+@CurrentState+''' and Process='''+@Process+''' and DateTime='''+@DateTime+''' and IPaddress='''+@IPaddress+''' and UploadedBytes='''+@UploadedBytes+''' and DownloadedBytes='''+@DownloadedBytes+''' and Duration='''+@Duration+''' and FileSize='''+@FileSize+''' and StreamId='''+@StreamId+''' and PlayerId='''+@PlayerId+''' and UserName='''+@UserName+''''
```

After @userName, look the 2 new ' in the end. It's the only change.
Tell me wether it worked